# Check Win32_group membership with powershell

Tags: windows, winapi, powershell

I want to know if a user whom username is delivered is member of a group whom groupname is delivered.

```
$u = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='$username'"
$g = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter "Name='$groupname'"
```

So I get two object with the property SID.

How can I check that user `$u` is member of group `$g`?

Comment: Do you have access to the module `activedirectory`? You can use the `Get-Aduser -memberof` to get this information as well.

Comment: I think I have no access to AD modules.

Comment: then my answer might help you.

Comment: You may want to use NTAccount class instead     System.Security.Principal.NTAccount

Comment: I dont understand what that comment is supposed to mean?

Comment: I have done this in vbs but not in powershell, not the time...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with an `Associators` query ([example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/67defa12-6ad1-439b-bd11-3abfc5b5208a/example-of-using-wmi-to-enumerate-group-membership?forum=winserverpowershell)). Which are notoriously slow but do work.

```
$u = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name='user'"
$group = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group -Filter "Name='group'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption

$u | foreach { 
    $query = “Associators Of {Win32_UserAccount.Domain='” `
    + $_.Domain + “',Name='” + $_.Name `
     + “'} WHERE AssocClass=Win32_GroupUser”    
    $memberOf = Get-WmiObject -Query $query | 
    select -ExpandProperty Caption

    If($memberOf -contains $group){
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is a member of $group"
    } Else {
        Write-Host "$($_.Name) is not a member of $group"
    }
}
```

Get the use you are looking for and group your are checking to see if the user is a member of. While `u$` should be only one user it is still a collection with one member. Pipe it into a `ForEach-Object` and build the `Associators` query. Execute the query and return all the group captions ( domain\groupname). Since `$memberof` is an array we can use `-contains` to see if the group you are looking for is there.

**Alternatively**

You could use the AD cmdlets if you have access to them and run the following

```
(Get-ADUser $user -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof) -contains (Get-ADGroup -Identity $group)
```

The above will return `True` or `False`. You can install Ad cmdlets by using `import-module activedirectory`

**Continued Testing**

OpenLDAP should support this from what I gather and it's much faster then the previous WMI.

```
$search = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectcategory=user)(Name=userFullName))"
$userLDAP = $search.FindOne().Path
$userMembers = ([ADSI]$userLDAP).memberof

$search = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectcategory=group)(Name=groupname))" 
$group = ($search.FindOne().Path) -replace "LDAP://"

$userMembers -contains $group
```

Sorry as I do not have access to OpenLDAP for testing. Do a search for a user and get the MemberOf as `$userMembers`. Then get the group into `$group`. Needed to remove the LDAP prefix from the string. Then just do another `-Contains` again.

Comment: I have tried the following code, it works (very slowly of course...) `$g.GetRelated('Win32_UserAccount')`.   Yes, it is actually worky but this is sheer slowness!!! (there is something like 1000 accounts)

Comment: Checking to see if a solution using `[adsi]` would be faster. @MUYBelgium

Comment: User are saved in OpenLDAP and not AD, does it makes a problem for the object [adsi]?

Comment: I will have to check. I dont know.

Comment: @MUYBelgium Check my updated answer. I am looking for some feedback from you